# JSOUP - extracing information from span

Tags: jsoup

Need to extract info from:

```
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Label">Phone:</div>
    <div class="Value">
      <span class="PersonPhoneNr">
         +355 445 670 
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tried:

```
Elements phoneNr = doc.select("[class=PersonPhoneNr]");
```

Got 0 results. The problem is only with span classes. JSOUP 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [selector syntax documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), you can select html tags by class using the `.` selector as in:

```
Elements spansWithPersonPhoneNrClass = doc.select("span.PersonPhoneNr");
```

Comment: +1. Your answer is spot on, and you provided a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too

```
Elements phoneNr = doc.getElementsByClass("PersonPhoneNr");
```

This answer is just an addition. Richard's answer is better because it allows you to specifically target span elements with the class (or just the class). What I want to say is that it's more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements phoneNr = doc.select("span[class=PersonPhoneNr]");
```

or more convenient way is:

```
.select("span.PersonPhoneNr")
```